# Extract hue channel from HSV image in Pillow

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library, color-channel

I'm trying to extract the `hue` channel from a pillow image. Below is an illustration:

```
In [40]: from PIL import Image
In [41]: pillow_img  = Image.open('lekha.jpg')

# convert to HSV    
In [42]: hsv_img = pillow_img.convert('HSV')

# cast it as NumPy array
In [43]: arr_hsv = np.asarray(hsv_img)
```

Now, how can I extract only the `hue` channel from the array `arr_hsv`?

If it's an RGB image, extracting the `red` channel would translate to:

```
red_channel =  arr_rgb[:, :, 0]
```

However, I'm unsure whether this is the same case for HSV as well.

Comment: It is also the case for HSV. The first channel is the hue, so you can select with `img[:, :, 0]`, or equivalently, `img[..., 0]`.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds would you like to add it as an answer so that we can close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same.

```
hue_channel =  arr_hsv[:, :, 0]
```